# Using np.maximum.reduceat to reduce an 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I had a 2D array, which a pair of float data coupled with index (shaped (3, k) float array).
I wanted to get the maximum value in `data[0]` for each indexes at `data[2]`, while also getting the same index data from `data[1]`

See Example below:

```py
data = np.array([[ 0.45114132,  0.31522008,  0.66176217,  0.45114132,  0.26872137],
       [11.        ,  6.        , 10.        ,  4.        ,  8.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ]])

# Expected Output:
array([[0.66176217, 0.45114132], [10., 4], [0, 1])
```

I could get the output from `np.maximum.reduceat` but only for the first row

```py
indx = np.unique(data[2].astype(int),return_index=1)[1]
np.maximum.reduceat(data[0], indx)
   # not works for the whole `data`
# Output
array([0.66176217, 0.45114132])
```

Also, I've tried to create a mask, but this doesn't always works as the example

```py
mask = np.maximum.reduceat(data[0], indx)
data[:, np.isin(data[0], mask)]

# Output
array([[ 0.45114132,  0.66176217,  0.45114132],
       [11.        , 10.        ,  4.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]])
```

Further note: I intended to prevent usage of any loops / list instantiations.
As handling a large amount of data would be too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `np.lexsort` You could combine everything into one line of code.

```
data[:,np.lexsort(data[[0, 2]])[np.r_[data[2,:-1] != data[2,1:], True]]]

array([[ 0.66176217,  0.45114132],
       [10.        ,  4.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ]])
```

Comment: My head is spinning from this one-liner, but +1 :)

Comment: @AndrejKesely its a work around the `np.unique` used by OP

Comment: The one-liner is really cool! But i didn't really understand what had been actually done by `np.r_[data[2,:-1] != data[2,1:], True]]`. Would you mind to explain it a bit?

Comment: @ycohui that part gives the indeces where the maximum resides once sorted. Ie the last index for each group

Answer (score 1):

I hope I've understood your question right. You can use [`np.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html#numpy.lexsort) to sort `row[0]` according `row[2]` and then use indices from `np.unique` to get the right values:

```py
idx = np.unique(data[2].astype(int), return_index=1)[1]
mask = np.lexsort([-data[0], data[2]])[idx]
print(data[:, mask])
```

Prints:

```
[[ 0.66176217  0.45114132]
 [10.          4.        ]
 [ 0.          1.        ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [75]: data = np.array([[ 0.45114132,  0.31522008,  0.66176217,  0.45114132,  0.26872137],
    ...:        [11.        ,  6.        , 10.        ,  4.        ,  8.        ],
    ...:        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ]])

In [76]: indx = np.unique(data[2].astype(int),return_index=1)[1]

In [77]: indx
Out[77]: array([0, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Just supply the whole array, and axis to get the max for all rows:

```
In [78]: np.maximum.reduceat(data, indx, axis=1)
Out[78]: 
array([[ 0.66176217,  0.45114132],
       [11.        ,  8.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ]])
```

This applies the max to each row independly.

### edit

To just take max for the first row, and returning the whole column, one way is to use `split` to break the array into blocks, and take the max of each block.

```
In [28]: datas = np.split(data, indx[1:], axis=1); datas
Out[28]: 
[array([[ 0.45114132,  0.31522008,  0.66176217],
        [11.        ,  6.        , 10.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]),
 array([[0.45114132, 0.26872137],
        [4.        , 8.        ],
        [1.        , 1.        ]])]

In [29]: [d[:,np.argmax(d[0])] for d in datas]
Out[29]: 
[array([ 0.66176217, 10.        ,  0.        ]),
 array([0.45114132, 4.        , 1.        ])]

In [30]: np.transpose(_)
Out[30]: 
array([[ 0.66176217,  0.45114132],
       [10.        ,  4.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ]])
```

Yes this does have a loop on the split blocks, but I'm not sure that it's much slower than the `reduceat`.  It may depend on the relative number of blocks compared to the total columns.  Generally a few iterations on a complex task has a decent performance.

p.s. `argmax` doesn't have a `reduceat`, so can't be applied the same way as `maximum`.

Comment: This does not match the expected output

Comment: I realized that `data[1]` values were different, but though it was just that he'd made a mistake, especially with the 4 instead of 8.  But looking further it appears that he doesn't want the reduceat applied to each row individually, but that the reduceat for the first row is supposed to take the whole column.